# How do you set the fps to 60 for the coral mipi camera

Tags: camera, google-coral

I am trying to set the fps of the coral mipi camera to 60fps. From the datasheet, it says it can run 720p at 60fps so i know the camera is capable.

I have set the resolution using the following command which works.

`v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video1 --set-fmt-video=width=1280,height=720`

but when I set the fps to 60, the max limit seem to be 30.

```
mendel@mocha-calf:~$ v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video1 -p 60
Frame rate set to 30.000 fps
```

There are no option to set exposure or gain. Would I have to rebuild the driver to be able to have these options?

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60 FPS not supported. Please see the supported formats below.

```
    mendel@tuned-rabbit:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT 
        Type: Video Capture 
        [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2) 
             Size: Discrete 640x480 
                   Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps) 
             Size: Discrete 720x480 
                   Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps) 
             Size: Discrete 1280x720 
                   Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps) 
             Size: Discrete 1920
```

And for changing/setting exposure and gain, you may need to make modifications in the current driver code and rebuild the kernel image. Driver code can be found at:

https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx/+/refs/heads/master/drivers/media/platform/mxc/capture/ov5645_mipi_v2.c#2774

And instructions to build the kernel image can be seen at : https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late, but better late than never.

I've been using Google's Coral Camera too. I found that the 30fps is really just up to the driver not supporting it. I've updated the driver and now I get 720p@60fps.

```
mendel@good-apple:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT 
  Type: Video Capture 
  [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2) 
    Size: Discrete 640x480 
      Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps) 
    Size: Discrete 720x480 
      Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps) 
    Size: Discrete 1280x720
      Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
      Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
```

I posted the driver patches and how to build/install on this issue: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/740.

I hope that is clear enough. If not, don't hesitate to ask. Good luck!